# Is it at, in, or on a dump?

Tags: prepositions

> The owners of a pub and sandwich bar in the village both said they knew nothing about their refuse being deposited **at** the illegal dump.
>
> Look for instance at plants: vandalized trees send out new shoots, grass grows **on** rubbish dumps, flowers spring up in scrap yards.

*(from [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dump))*

> Other groups dumped waste **at** the site, which legally could only accept trees and other natural materials. Groups put illicit materials **in** the dump, such as household appliances.

*(from [here](https://www.arkansasonline.com/news/2020/jan/25/dump-fire-liability-back-in-question-20/))*

I feel stupid because I struggle to see any system behind all this. Which preposition should I use in one case or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"at" for talking about the dump as a point on the map.

"in" if you are thinking of a container which you can put rubbish in

"on" if you are thinking about a pile of rubbish (which might be covered by soil)

The local dump is a place and you might throw away stuff at the dump.  But it might also be a big pile of rubbish.  If you throw stuff away at a dump like that you actually put it on the rubbish dump.  Or the dump might be like a big hole in the ground, or a big container. If so you put your rubbish in the dump.  Different prepositions are used to describe different meanings with different types of dump.